# How does a client machine knows about the fact that which port it has to connect on server or server provides such information.?

Tags: c#

I want to know that in communication between client and server how a client machine comes to know that for fulfilling a particular request it has to connect to a specific port of the server. And while the server has to give response message, how it comes to know that it has to connect to a specific client. Does the server provides any information to client that it has to connect to a particular port.

Answer (score 1):

The client needs to know what port to connect to.
Some protocols have default ports, like HTTP has port 80 if nothing else is specified.

To ask the server for a port is "impossible" since to ask that you need to connect to a port and then you need to know the number of the "ask"-port.
In some protocols you can actually connect to a standard port and as for a port to open a back channel on that port, but you still know the port number for the initial connection.

Comment: If suppose i am on client machine and i want to send request to server then how i can know that i have to mention a specific port say port 80 for fulfilling this request or how does my machine knows that it has to send this request message on port 80.

Comment: is there any such mechanism that i just send the data on any port and then it is redirected by server to the required port

Comment: I want to ask- is this required to be known by a person doing coding on client machine that it has to use a specific port . Or is there any other mechanism

Comment: No, the server can't direct you to a port. You have to address exactly one port and know that port beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> ...how a client machine comes to know that for fulfilling a particular request it has to connect to a specific port of the server.

The client is either told directly what port to use (for instance, `http://example.com:123` tells your browser to do HTTP on port 123), or uses a ["well known" port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) (one that it "knows" because that information is built into its code). There are lots of "well known" ports -- 80 for HTTP, 22 for SSH, 110 for POP3...

> And while the server has to give response message, how it comes to know that it has to connect to a specific client.

When the client connects to the server, it's via something called a "socket." The server just answers back on the same socket. If you're interested in the technical details, you'll need to look in depth at the way TCP/IP works, but IIRC the client IP and the port on the client (the "source port") are both in the TCP packets the server receives, so the server knows what address and port to reply to. At the level of using sockets, you (the server) just send to the socket that was established when the client connected.

Comment: I have understood the answer of second part of the question but please tell me in more detail that how does a client knows that it has to send a specific data on a specific port.....whose responsibility is this i mean who handles it.

Comment: @user3843784: It's the responsibility of the person writing the client. Let's take the web browser example: The people writing web browsers let the user tell the browser what port to use (in the URL, `http://example.com:123`), but if the user *doesn't* tell the browser what port to use, the people writing the browser have written into the code of the browser that it should use port 80. That's just hardcoded information, based on the fact that the default port for HTTP is port 80.

Comment: Now suppose if i have to send a data packet from one machine to other on LAN and i am writing code for client side, you mean that i have to mention the port no in my code for that. But how do i know that i have to mention a particular port no to send a data packet. Can i assign random port no..??

Comment: @user3843784: If you're creating the server/protocol, you can choose the port number. Note that on on \*nix systems, in order for a process to listen for connections on a port lower than 1024, the process needs root permissions, so you may want a port higher than that.

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

A single server listens on a port number. *Think of a sea port, where ships can enter and transfer their resources & take resources to another country. When the port is open, it accepts ships to enter it and perform actions. But if the port is closed, the ship will not be able to enter it.* **It's the same** as networking ports. If the port in your internet router is closed, no one connection will be able to successfully perform networking actions through it. Think of a port like a station, where networking packets go through.

Now usually, an HTTP server runs on port 80, means it will listen to new clients on port 80. Now popular web-browsers by default are configured to load connections on port 80, because it's the default world-wide port number for HTTP web pages. If you will change the default port to 81, and try to connect to a website which is hosted on port 80, your connection will drop, unless the server you're trying to access via HTTP protocol listens on port 81 too.

Now besides HTTP, let's say you have a game server, it's the same but just with a live connection (considering HTTP servers is one-execute connection, generates response header and kills the connection), you can decide any port for your game server, same as you can decide any port number for any listener, let's say 4557. If you want clients to connect to your game server, the port number must be the same as the server's port, because that's the port the server uses to transfer connections through.

## Old

*Your client should already know the port target it will connect to.
There are different types of servers, for exanple the HTTP server, usually listens on port 80. When your browser sends a request and it reaches the server, the client (your browser) sends a request header along with it. The server usually accepts the client, reads his request and generates a response header and writes it to the client, and kills the connection.
Some servers with live connection work in a similar way, except it caches the connected clients and handles them all at once.*